# Return Certain Value Only With Certain Parameters

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine, spy

In Jasmine, is there any way to return a certain value from a spy only if it was called with certain parameters? For example, can I have something like:

```
describe('my test', function() {
  beforeEach(function() {
    this.mySpy = jasmine.createSpy();

    // not sure how to do this, so this is pseudocode
    this.mySpy.and.returnValue(true).when.calledWith(false);
    this.mySpy.and.returnValue(false).when.calledWith(true);
  });

  it('returns true if called with false', function() {
    expect(this.mySpy(false)).toEqual(true);
  });

  it('returns false if called with true', function() {
    expect(this.mySpy(true)).toEqual(false);
  });
});
```

I looked through the docs, but couldn't quite find what I wanted, and couldn't find anything related by searching. I can see why there wouldn't be a case for this - you know what you are calling, and when, and why, and with what parameters, so why make anything more specific? At the same time, this could result in more code, when you could specify exactly what you want to return once, and not have to specify it again.

Comment: I am actually running into the same issue. Looking forward to a reply.

Comment: I'm not going to be using your method, as it is sort of redundant, but it looks like a good method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran into this same problem today. The way I fixed it was by calling a fake method instead of the "someMethod" and handling the params to return the desired return value:

```
spyOn(SomeObj, "someMethod").and.callFake(function (property ) {
                        if (property === "someValue") {
                            return "someReturnValue";
                        } else if (property === "someOtherValue") {
                            return "someOtherReturnValue";
                        }
                    });
```

Comment: It's a little verbose & redundant, but I suppose it could work in a pinch.

Comment: With what comes out of the box from Jasmine, I don't really see any other way to do it other than what I provided. I'd appreciate if you could show how to make it less verbose and redundant to see another option. Thank you!

Comment: I don't know one (besides obviously things like trinary expressions, which are confusing and often unclear), I was saying I wish there were :(.

Comment: @trysis right, it would be nice if there was a nicer out of he box option. In either case I would appreciate if you could mark my answer as accepted. Thanks!

Comment: Sorry, I was waiting for other answers but I suppose other answers are not going to come.